# EXC_BAD_ACCES after trying to allocate 2D array

Tags: c, malloc, exc-bad-access

I'm working on a project for school and am trying to use two 2D arrays. This is part of the code

```
int **matrice_prezent, **matrice_next;
```

Trying to allocate memory to both using this bit:

```
*matrice_prezent = (int *)malloc((linii+2) * sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i<linii+1; i++)
    matrice_prezent[i] = (int *)malloc((coloane+2) * sizeof(int));

*matrice_next = (int *)malloc((linii) * sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i<linii; i++)
    matrice_next[i] = (int *)malloc((coloane) * sizeof(int));
```

First part works great, no issues. Trying to do the same thing to `matrice_next` however, results in this error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Using the debugger(I am using Xcode btw, forgot to mention) I see that at the beginning of the code (`int **matrice_prezent, **matrice_next`) the first one has an address `0x...` while the latter has `NULL`.

I understand that this error means I'm trying to use memory that isn't available(or something along those lines). I'm not sure if it's a mistake on my part (since the first set of `malloc` works), or if I have to force it somehow to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `*matrice_prezent = (int *)malloc((linii+2) * sizeof(int));` --> `matrice_prezent = (int **)malloc((linii+2) * sizeof(int*));`. ditto. BTW Cast from `void*` does not need.

Comment: if linii or coloane are large, it's possible that you receive NULL as result of the malloc() because tehre is no longer memory left.  Allways check !

Comment: In fact, the first gives the impression that it works. THe fact that you don't get an exec-bad-access is no guarantee that it works as you think:  `matrice_prezent` is uninitialized, and when you write `*matrice_prezent` you dereference this unitialized pointer.  It's undefined behaviour.  The result of malloc is stored somewhere but not in matrice_prezent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definition of `int **` you should proceed as follow:

```
matrice_prezent = (int **)malloc((linii+2) * sizeof(int*));  // HEY *matrice_prezent is matrize_present[0] !!
assert (matrice_present != NULL);    // allways check memory allocation result
for(i = 0; i<linii+1; i++) {          // as previously 
    matrice_prezent[i] = (int *)malloc((coloane+2) * sizeof(int));
    assert (matrice_prezent[i] != NULL);   // really allways ! ;-)
    }
```

For the second, proceed in the same way than for the first.  If you do this often, it would be worth creating a function that does this:

```
int** alloc2D (int lines, int cols) { /* ... */ }
```

***Remark:***  you could consider using [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/?kw=calloc) instead of `malloc()` because it's well suited for arrays.  In addition, it sets all the elements allocated to 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works well now. I'm now trying to make a new function void alloc_array(int **v, int n, int m) to do this, but after the call alloc_array(matrice_prezent,linii+2,coloane+2) it once again results in a EXC_BAD_CALL after something like this scan("%d",&matrice_prezent[1][1])

Comment: If you do assign a value to v in `void alloc_aray(int**v, int m,int n)`, you'll modify a local pointer to that function: the original pointer will never get updated.  Try `int** aloc_array(int m, int n) { int **v; /* your code here */ return v; }` and then `matrice_prezent=alloc_array(...);`